# How to create a secret string with JWT_KEY in Node.JS app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, jwt

I'm developing a Node.JS & MongoDB app inserting articles and categories, with a signup and login users system. I need to add/fix a secret string on order to make Jsonwebtoken (JWT_KEY) work properly.

My authentication or authorization fails when I try to add an article with details (title, attached picture ect.) threw Postman, probably because I made a mistake installing or using the **jsonwebtoken** library. It maybe a mistake in the nodemon.json file that is should be hidden at the end (user, password, **JWT_KEY)**, but maybe in another part of my code.

The Postman process connects with the **article.js routes file**, that seems to be fine. The relevant part is the createArticle POST, since the rest work fine so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const upload = require('../middlewares/upload');
const checkAuth = require('../middlewares/checkAuth');

const {
        getAllArticles,
        createArticle,
        getArticle,
        updateArticle,
        deleteArticle
 } = require('../controllers/articles');

router.get('/', getAllArticles);
router.get('/:articleId', getArticle);

router.post('/', checkAuth, upload.single('image'), createArticle);
router.patch('/:articleId', checkAuth, updateArticle);
router.delete('/:articleId', checkAuth, deleteArticle);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the **authChek.js middleware** that is responsible of the authorization process:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split('')[1];
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
        next();
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Auth failed'
        })
    }
}

module.exports =  checkAuth;
```

The verify seems ok and should work fine connecting to nodemon. If it's all fine, Postman should return back a message that the authorization succeeded - but it returns failed auth. Here, in the **article.js controller**, the POST method seems fine to and should not catch an error of 500, 401 or 409:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Article = require('../models/article');
const Category = require('../models/category');

module.exports = {
    createArticle: (req, res) => {
        const { path: image } = req.file;
        const { title, description, content, categoryId } = req.body;

        Category.findById(categoryId).then((category) => {
            if (!category) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Category not found'
                })
            }

            const article = new Article({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                title,
                description,
                content,
                categoryId,
                image: image.replace('\\','/')
            });

            return article.save();
        }).then(() => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Created article'
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Another file using the JWT_KEY is the **users.js controller**, in the login part. Look at the area of the if & result. It may fail to connect properly to the .env part of the nodemon.json file. See here "process.env.JWT_KEY":

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = {
    login: (req, res) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        User.find({ email }).then((users) => {
            if (users.length === 0) {
                return res.status(401).json ({
                message: 'Authentication failed'
                });
            }

            const [ user ] = users;

            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    return res.status(401).json({
                        message: 'Authentication failed'
                    });
                }

                if (result) {
                    const token = jwt.sign({
                        id: user._id,
                        email: user.email,
                    },
                     process.env.JWT_KEY,
                     { 
                        expiresIn: "1H"
                     });

                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Authentication successful',
                    token
                })
            }

            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Authentication failed'
                });
            })    
        })
    }
}
```

Is there something to fix here? Or how can I check if my JWT_KEY in nodemon.json is written properly or wrong? If the string is generated by a library or taken from somewhere else, I don't know where to search for it in my app or around the web.

Comment: what is the error it shows you

Comment: I get this false in Postman:
 
{
    "message": "Auth failed"
}

Comment: A suggestion, instead of `process.env.JWT_KEY` start with static hard-coded jwt key where you sign and verify. Update the question where you get `{ "message": "Auth failed" } ` error, because there are 3 places where you can get this error.

Comment: What are you splitting the authorization header on - **req.headers.authorization.split('')[1]**, there should ideally be a space here if you are using "**Bearer hash**" format.

Comment: Sulyman: The error is "Auth failed - checkAuth" - connected to the checkAuth.js file, arror 401. Now you can see what it is?
Ayush - Done. It douse not change the error status.

Comment: Can you console.log the error object?

Comment: When I add console.log, it prints "[Function: checkAuth]"

Is it helpful?

Comment: As a follow up to @Ayush comment, there is an issue in the `checkAuth` middleware, you are passing an empty string to the split method, this is wrong, it should be a string with a single empty space. The authorization header is something like this `Bearer tokenStringHere`, the space separating `Bearer` and `tokenStringHere` should be used for splitting. Can you try updating the line getting the token value to this: `const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];` and see if anything changes?

Comment: @Ayush I've changed it and it has a space (' '), and I added the tokenString threw the user POST method. Now, it doesn't changeand the error chatched is still  "message": "Auth failed - checkAuth".
What can I do more?

Comment: Can you put a console.log(error) inside the catch block? Something like below. 


---------------------------
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split('')[1];
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
        next();
    } catch(error) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Auth failed'
        })
    }
}

module.exports =  checkAuth;

Comment: This console.log(error); in the catch blok says:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at checkAuth (C:\xampp\htdocs\apiexp\api\middlewares\checkAuth.js:5:49).

5:49 is the split here:
const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

Comment: That definitely means that authorization key in headers object is undefined. It will for sure work with correct headers.

Comment: Tell me if you meen the following code. This part I checked and it's fine. 
----------------------------------------------
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});